# How to share a apk from my app to whatsapp in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, filepath, file-sharing

I want to share an app apk with WhatsApp when a certain button gets pressed. Here is my attempt and circumstances: 
The Code is as follows:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
                Uri uri;
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.setType("plain/text");
                uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.simon.easycounter/counter.apk");
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
                sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                startActivity(sendIntent);
           }
```

The apk file is located in the package com.simon.easycounter, where the Java Class files are.

I tried a lot with different file paths, I tried different MIME Types like "*/*", "application/*", nothing worked. When pressing the send button in WhatsApp an Message from WhatsApp appears, which says something like "Failed to share, try again later."

Does anybody know how to solve the problem?

---Update---

I created a FileProvider now:

In My Manifest.xml:

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths"/>
        </provider>
```

My filepaths.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <files-path name="files" path="/" />
        <cache-path name="cache" path="/"/>
    </paths>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

And here is my updated Code when the Button gets pressed:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
                File newFile = getActivity().getFileStreamPath("counter.apk");
                Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, newFile);

                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
                sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                startActivity(sendIntent);
}
```

Is this the right way to copy the apk to a file and create the Uri? What is the problem that it does not work? still same error Message on WhatsApp

Comment: `plain/text` is not a valid MIME type, let alone the correct MIME type for an APK file. Your APK file is in the wrong place in your project if you expect to use `android.resource` as a scheme. And `android.resource` is not a valid scheme for `EXTRA_STREAM` -- it is supposed to be `content`. So, copy your content to a file, use `FileProvider` to share that file via a `Uri` with a `content` scheme, and use the correct MIME type for APK files (`application/vnd.android.package-archive`).

Comment: please this https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28000012